# how memory is being allocated in c for unsigned short

Tags: c, variables, memory-management

```
main()
{
while(1)
    {
    if(j==7)
        {
        unsigned short Alphabet[10]; //what is size of this variable 
/* if i came out of this loop will the memory allocated be cleared? if not then how to clear it? */
        }
    }
}
```

What is the size of Alphabet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Alphabet` is an array of 10 `unsigned short` elements. Its size is `10 * sizeof (unsigned short)`, where `sizeof (unsigned short)` is commonly 2, but it can vary for different implementations.

In the terms used by the standard, `Alphabet` has *automatic storage duration*. That means that it's created on entry to the innermost containing block (in this case, delimited by the nearest `{` and `}`) and ceases to exist on exit from that block. (Typically it will be allocated on "the stack", but the language standard doesn't actually use that term, and some compilers might use a different strategy.)

When I say that it "ceases to exist", I don't mean that it's *necessarily* cleared or popped off the stack. It just means that you're no longer allowed to try to access it. (You could try to do so by saving a pointer to the object and dereferencing it outside the block; if you do that, your code's behavior is undefined.)

Basically, `Alphabet` exists only while the innermost enclosing block is executing. The compiler can implement that any way it likes. It's common for the actual allocation to occur when the function is called, and for the stack to be popped when the function returns, but conceptually `Alphabet` ceases to exist at the end of the block even if the memory hasn't been explicitly deallocated.

Comment: if i create .hex file for this code then how it effect the size of .hex file.Since i m coding for microcontroller so i want my code to be shortest in size and memory

Comment: The size of the executable most likely won't be affected. The compiler will generate code that allocates memory for `Alphabet` during execution. If it allocates, say, 20 bytes, that doesn't take twice as much code as allocating 10 bytes. It will, of course, affect the amount of memory allocated as your program is running. And the best way to determine memory usage is to try it and measure it yourself.

Comment: I don't really expect an explanation for the downvote, but if you think there was something wrong with my answer I'd appreciate some feedback on how you think it can be improved.